Entity Framework Core can't find main web project when we set it to run on 32-bit
I have been helping update an old DLL into a REST API. The old DLL had a plethora of references to other DLL's, including one we need that was written in Visual Basic.
This DLL also needs to run in 32-bit, which is causing issues when trying to do code-first database development. The .csproj file in the main API project has <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> at the top. This is how the lead on the project has gotten the VB project to work with the project.
Here is the top of the .csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

But when the <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> is there, we get this error when trying to run any code-first operation (Add-Migration, Remove-Migration etc.):

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Project.Api, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Project.Api, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.get_StartupAssembly()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.get_MigrationsOperations()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load file or assembly 'Project.Api, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have been looking for a few hours, both through issues on the .NET github and on StackOverflow to no avail.
I have verified that removing <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> allows us to use those functions. I have also added <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> to the Project.Database.csproj but it just tells me it can't find the Project.Database.csproj now.
We could just remove that from the .csproj file every time we want to make database changes, but I was wondering if there was a fix we could find.

Can you run your ef migrations commands with --runtime win-x86 option? See this link for more help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options

I cannot run the command with that. I just tried it and received the same error. I ran this command to be clear: dotnet-ef migrations add MigrationName--context ProjectDbContext --runtime win-x86 -s Project.Api -p Project.Database @SoftwareDveloper

The solution is to build the migration host rather than use dotnet-ef. If I know how to do that I would post an answer; but we used to use EF here and know it's the answer.

Hmm, I will look into building the migration host. A lead is better than what I have. Thanks @Joshua
